# How to store only PDF type of Binaries in my storage extension using Custom DAO in Tridion 2011

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011, tridion-content-delivery, tridion-storage-extension

I have written custom DAO to **Add**/Update/Delete specific records for my Binaries in my persistence type of storage extension in Tridion 2011.

Below is sample code where I am trying to use my custom DAO class/interface (`PublishActionDAO` and `PublishAction`) in my custom binary DAO (`JPABinaryDAOExtension`).

```
public class JPABinaryDAOExtension extends JPABinaryContentDAO implements BinaryContentDAO 
{

    public JPABinaryDAOExtension(String storageId, EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory, String storageName) 
    {
        super(storageId, entityManagerFactory, storageName);
    }

    public JPABinaryDAOExtension(String storageId, EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory, EntityManager entityManager, String storageName) 
    {
        super(storageId, entityManagerFactory, entityManager, storageName);
    }

    public void create(final BinaryContent binaryContent, final String relativePath) throws StorageException 
    {
        super.create(binaryContent, relativePath);  
        String url = relativePath;
        String tcmURI = Integer.toString(binaryContent.getBinaryId());
        PublishActionDAO publishActionDAO = (PublishActionDAO) StorageManagerFactory.getDefaultDAO("PublishAction");
        PublishAction publishAction = new PublishAction();
        publishAction.setAction("Add");
        publishAction.setUrl(url);
        publishAction.setTcmUri(tcmURI);
        publishActionDAO.store(publishAction);
    }
}
```

Above is sample code for **Add** when a new binary is created and same goes for Update and Delete, I am going to store Action as **Add**, binary publish URL, its TCMURI. I can get these data easily in above code. Now the problem which I am facing is that I just need to store records for PDFs types of Binaries only and for other type of binaries like (JPG/Word etc.) no record entry.

Edit: Is below solution will work for me or making object for binaries it will slow down the performance.

```
ItemDAO item = (ItemDAO) StorageManagerFactory.getDAO(binaryContent.getPublicationId(),StorageTypeMapping.BINARY_META);
BinaryMeta binarymeta = (BinaryMeta) item.findBinaryByPrimaryKey(binaryContent.getPublicationId(),binaryContent.getBinaryId());
binarymeta.getBinaryType();
```

Comment: OK. Now we're getting somewhere (I'll delete my previous comments as they are obsolete).

Comment: Do you **have** a performance problem? It is unlikely you'll find any faster way to look up a binary than using `findBinaryByPrimaryKey`, even more so if you use object caching (as you should).

Comment: @thanks frank, I was just curious about performance when my solution goes on production where actual publishing goes on, is above solution implemented above is best or what more changes I can do to get the Binaries data and one more this do we have any API references for the Tridion storage extension classes

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Strictly checking for the type can be done by verifying the extension of the `relativePath` in your `create` method:

```
    if (!relativePath.toLowerCase().endsWith(".pdf")) { return; }
```

However, there is a better way of handling this -- in your `cd_storage_conf.xml`, map the Binary type using a specific extension. Then the CD storage framework will only call your DAO if the extension matches:

```
    <Item typeMapping="Binary" itemExtension=".pdf" storageId="myStorage"/>
```

Comment: @Mihai...thanks I will try same tomorrow and update the answer accordingly.